# Microsoft Edge (only) not ending session when closing browser?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, microsoft-edge

I have a PHP site that makes use of sessions, which obviously are not supposed to be able to persist if you close your browser. I've done this scores of times, no issues.

And no issue currently - except within Microsoft's new Edge browser. If the user logs in, works in the site, closes Edge's window in the top right corner, and then re-opens the page and pastes the web address (or bookmarked it before), all their variables from the previous visit are still present. That's a problem, as each visit the viewer will likely want to give/lookup changing information.

I've successfully replicated the problem in Edge. What I can't figure out is why Edge is doing it. Every other browser kills the session and all its variables upon closing of the window (tested all the major browsers, including Internet Explorer). The only thing I can think of is Edge isn't actually closing as a program when the window is closing. Has anyone else ran into this problem? I can't find anything in the forums.

Comment: Check the network tab, specifically the cookies being set. Do they have an expiry? If the expiry of the session cookie is 0, then you're right there is a problem. The next thing to check is when you exit out of Edge, check the Task Manager and see if the process has ended - if not then sessions/cookies may persist. If the expiry is 0 and the process fully ends when you exit, then that sounds like an Edge bug to me.

Comment: I advise not to invest too much time into this. My daily experience is that the Edge browser seems to be in a very early state, it is full of small but annoying little bugs that change every week. Sad, but it seems that MS uses the users for quality testing.

Comment: It's looking like an Edge bug. All other browsers are terminating/expiring correctly and Edge is not still running in the background after closing.

Comment: Works for me. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible the session ended, but there is a bug with the cache.

I noticed that Edge is very aggressive with using cached pages.  It would show a signed in page even after the user signed off (actually killing their session and updating the session cookie) because it would not respect the etag or any other cache instructions.  I had to specifically prevent IE11 and Edge from caching at all.